# Matlab transfer function cannot sum correctly

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math

I have 2 different transfer function in form of fraction. Both denominators of functions are the same but when I write A+B, matlab does not notice and sum.

```
A =              0.0041 s^2 + 0.001s
        -------------------------------------------
       4.244e-12 s^3 + 1.224e-07 s^2 + 8e-07 s + 1


B =           0.0001 s + 0.001
       -------------------------------------------
       4.244e-12 s^3 + 1.224e-07 s^2 + 8e-07 s + 1
```

Both denominators are the same but denominator of the result is multiply for sum of denominators of A and B.

Do you why?

Comment: I edited @SardarUsama now the same

Comment: not multipyly, it is sum results. I tried to sum but it multply.

Comment: yes I also say matlab does not notice the sum for same denominators.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the unsimplified transfer function, since MATLAB does not simplify it after doing any operation that involves transfer functions.

You can get simplified value by using `minreal(A+B)`.

It will remove non-observable states from the state space model. Translated to the transfer function model, it will cancel zero-pole pairs.